# What happens when an attacker sends fake nonce in TKIP handshake?

Tags: wifi, wireless, wpa2

The TKIP handshake is halfway completed; the access point and station have exchanged the first two messages. Now, before the access point can send the third message to the station an attacker sends a fake message containing the authentic MAC of the access point, the correct sequence number, but a fake nonce. What would an attacker be able to do with this attack? Also, is the MIC that is part of this message ever checked by the station?